# JavaScript: Add new property to array items using .forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

```
let foods = [
  { name: 'bread', carbs: 36, protein: 8, fat: 2 },
  { name: 'mayo mustard mix', carbs: 0, protein: 0, fat: 10 },
  { name: 'turkey', carbs: 0, protein: 25, fat: 1 },
  { name: 'cheese', carbs: 0, protein: 5, fat: 7 },
]
```

I need to calculate the calories by multiplying carbs, protein, and fat together and then add the results together.

Im pretty stuck on this one, i've gotten to

```
foods.forEach((element, index, array => { })
```

but not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: What's the major issue? You have the element, you likely can figure out how to calculate the calories, what's the specific issue? How to add a property to an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each food item, get its three values and save the calculation, if I remember it correctly :), in a new property `calories`:

```js
let foods = [ 
  { name: 'bread', carbs: 36, protein: 8, fat: 2 }, 
  { name: 'mayo mustard mix', carbs: 0, protein: 0, fat: 10 }, 
  { name: 'turkey', carbs: 0, protein: 25, fat: 1 }, 
  { name: 'cheese', carbs: 0, protein: 5, fat: 7 }
];

foods.forEach(food => {
  const { carbs = 0, protein = 0, fat = 0 } = food;
  food.calories = carbs * 4 + protein * 4 + fat * 9;
});

console.log(foods);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function calculate_calories ( food ) { return something }
// this function should calculate the calories from input
// I assume you will do this one yourself

foods.forEach( food => {
  var cal = calculate_calories ( food )
  food.calories = cal
})
```

That's it. I hope it's understandable enough.

Comment: @DaveNewton I answered almost simultaneously with the other person and our answers are pretty much the same, except that he gives more details :)